# POST request to url that has query string parameters

Tags: forms, http

System I have to update has http-handlers that are accessible via address like

```
http://<server>/handlers?name=some-handler-name
```

I added http form with action tag that directs to one of this handlers like this:

```
<form ... action="/handlers?name=some-handler-name" >
```

My form is a part of a system and located right on the same server. Basically its accessible via adress like

```
http://<server>/handlers?name=my-handler-with-form
```

But when I submit my form - nothing is posted to *some-handler-name* handler because my http-request receives code 302 (redirect).

Do I use correct address in action method (what I want is my form data to be posted to address like http://server/handlers?name=some-handler-name)?

Is it possible to post data to url that has query string parameters?

I guess that system intercept my postback and for some reason redirects it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Correct address is important
2. Yes, it is possible to post data with query params
3. There would be some redirect rule set at the server side. You would need to work with server side dev or read server side deployment/code documentation.

Comment: That's right. I've figured out that there are some special rules how to post data to handlers in system I work with